# Why is Shepherd Book crushing a snake on the cover of Serenity: The Shepherd's Tale?

Tags: comics, firefly, serenity, cover-art, symbols

[image: *Serenity: The Shepherd's Tale* cover]

Have any of the writers or artists stated why Shepherd Book is stepping on a snake on the cover of *Serenity: The Shepherd's Tale*? There is no snake in the graphic novel. Is it a allusion to Book overcoming adversity? It may be a reference to this Bible passage, but I doubt is as it doesn't really connect to the story:

> 14 So the Lord God said to the serpent, “Because you have done this,
>   “Cursed are you above all livestock
>       and all wild animals!
>   You will crawl on your belly
>       and you will eat dust
>       all the days of your life.
>   15 And I will put enmity
>       between you and the woman,
>       and between your offspring and hers;
>   he will crush your head,
>       and you will strike his heel.”

Answer (score 9):

Jesus or Mary crushing a snake with his/her foot is a fairly common theme in religious illustration in Western art. The snake generally represents evil, Satan, or people who talk at the theater.

I particularly like this one by Caravaggio: [https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madonna_and_Child_with_St.*Anne*(Dei_Palafrenieri)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madonna_and_Child_with_St._Anne_(Dei_Palafrenieri))

In-universe, Shepherd doesn't overtly belong to any specific Christian denomination; nevertheless, he is clearly Christian. *And* he is a good guy. My guess is that the snake is a nod on the illustrator's part to those two things. That way there is no need to do stuff like include a cross or have Shepherd cheesily battle evil. And it pleases art history nerds (which illustrators often are themselves).

Comment: I don't mind downvotes, but this one confuses me. Explain?

Comment: That may well be true, but I fail to see how it answers the question asked. Does Book see himself as Jesus? What evil does the snake represent?

Comment: @Richard The question asks why he is crushing a snake, and whether it is an allusion to overcoming adversity. The answer is yes - with an art history twist. How does that not answer the question?

Comment: ...You see, crushing the snake is a historically common symbol for being a force for good. It doesn't have to be specific. Look at the painting by Caravaggio in the link. Does the snake represent Satan in it? Probably not, it would be unusual to have baby Jesus or Mary crushing Satan. Rather, it represents evil. Any specific evil? Probably not. Western Art history has its symbols. Crushing the snake, baby with wings, dove, boy with bow/arrow, etc.

Comment: As I said in an earlier comment, *"The symbology is obvious. The choice of symbology isn't."*

Comment: @Richard I suppose we have to agree to disagree.  Given the context of Christianity, illustration, and the the personality of the character, I find the choice of symbolism as straightforward as they come.

Comment: And I stand ready to upvote you as soon as you can back up your answer with actual proof that that's what the artist had in mind.

Comment: @Richard I am sorry, I really cannot think of a way to make my point clearer.  If I think of a way to do that, I'll change it.

Comment: Book does belong to a specific denomination and is definitely a Christian. Hence the title "Shepherd."

Comment: @RogueJedi Which denomination?  As far as I know, it isn't ever specified.  And yes, he's definitely a Christian, there is more than enough evidence of that (and my answer depends on him being one) - but it's never overtly stated.

Comment: He calls himself a Christian in *Serinity*.

Comment: @RogueJedi Hmm...  I'm curious where he says that.  But I'll take your word for it, especially since it favors my answer :)  For now I'll delete the part where it says he isn't advertently Christian.  As for his specific denomination, that is never stated.  The most we can say about him is that he is clearly Protestant, rather than Catholic or Orthodox.  Or that he's some future Space Christian.

Comment: @MishaRosnach http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/12641/51226

Comment: @RogueJedi Thanks - I'll take it!

Answer (score 3):

Probably a reference to [Exodus 4:1-5](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=exodus%204:1-4:5&version=NKJV):

> 4 Then Moses answered and said, “But suppose they will not believe me
>   or listen to my voice; suppose they say, ‘The Lord has not appeared to
>   you.’”
>
> 2 So the Lord said to him, “What is that in your hand?”
>
> He said, “A rod.”
>
> 3 And He said, “Cast it on the ground.” So he cast it on the ground,
>   and it became a serpent; and Moses fled from it. 4 Then the Lord said
>   to Moses, “Reach out your hand and take it by the tail” (and he
>   reached out his hand and caught it, and it became a rod in his hand),
>   5 “that they may believe that the Lord God of their fathers, the God
>   of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob, has appeared to
>   you.”

Moses was a shepherd, remember?

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question asked; "***Have any of the writers or artists** stated why Shepherd Book is stepping on a snake on the cover of Serenity: The Shepherd's Tale?*". Unless you happen to be one of the writers or artists, obviously.

Comment: Given that he seems to be a Christian, I think it's more likely be a reference to Luke 10:19 -- http://biblehub.com/luke/10-19.htm

Comment: @Hypnosifl He's definitely [Christian](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12622/what-is-shepherd-books-religion)

Comment: None of which answers the question. The symbology is obvious. The choice of symbology isn't.

Comment: @Richard - Short of a quote from the cover designer we can't answer definitively, but the meaning of the symbol seems fairly transparent--he's also shown throwing away pictures of scenes from his past that all involve violence and anger (including the scene of him garroting the original Derrial Book in order to steal his name), and since Luke 10:19 seems to be about the Christian faith allowing believers to overcome Satan, the symbol is presumably about his faith helping him to overcome the influence of his own violent past, or the parts of himself that led him to be that way in the past.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - I don't disagree with any of that. That being said, none of this answers the fundamental question; "*Have any of the writers or artists stated why Shepherd Book is stepping on a snake on the cover of Serenity: The Shepherd's Tale?*"

Answer (score 2):

It could also be a reference to St Patrick, who cast the snakes out of Ireland.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Patrick#St._Patrick_banishes_all_snakes_from_Ireland

Of course this is just speculation.